# How to solve the tkinter button that is continually pressed when the program do a big loop?

Tags: python, tkinter

Actually, i want to create a GUI to receive data via serial port, but i got a  problem is that the button will be pressed continually till the whole data collation to be finished.

In order to make people to understand the situation what i encountered easily, i change the code in the bellow

```
from Tkinter import *

class GUIDemo(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()
        # self.datarcv()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.inputText = Label(self)
        self.inputText["text"] = "Input:"
        self.inputText.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.inputField = Entry(self)
        self.inputField["width"] = 50
        self.inputField.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=6)

        self.regist = Button(self, command=self.datasave)
        self.regist["text"] = "button"
        self.regist.grid(row=2, column=0)

    def datasave(self):
        a=0
        while a<100000000:
            a+=1
            print a



if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = GUIDemo(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a thread

```
from Tkinter import *
import threading

class GUIDemo(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()
        # self.datarcv()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.inputText = Label(self)
        self.inputText["text"] = "Input:"
        self.inputText.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.inputField = Entry(self)
        self.inputField["width"] = 50
        self.inputField.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=6)

        self.regist = Button(self, command=self.datasave_thread)
        self.regist["text"] = "button"
        self.regist.grid(row=2, column=0)

    def datasave_thread(self):
        self.thread = threading.Thread(None, self.datasave, None, (), {})
        self.thread.start()

    def datasave(self):
        a=0
        while a<100000000:
            a+=1
            print a



if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = GUIDemo(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: And, with the thread comes all the fun of thread synchronization and coordination.  Make sure to protect your data structures in case someone presses the button again before datasave completes!

Comment: Wow! for me, "thread" is a new thing, thank you so much
I've learned a new thing

Comment: Note: you don't necessarily _need_ a thread. It really depends on the work being done. If you can break it into small pieces you can get by with the main thread and just doing one piece at a time with the `after` command.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!!